# Javascript wrong validator

Tags: html

Hello I have a number field and whatever number I enter the field directly becomes red and the digits too,any ideas how can I find where this strange validation is perform and remove it?

```
  <input type="number" id="ee-amount" name="eeAmount" step="0.01" min="0" max="0.00" value="0" required="">
```

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: Post your html please!

Comment: There you go guys :)

Comment: Nothing turns red when I try that code. You need to provide a complete [mcve].

Comment: I cannot [reproduce it](http://jsbin.com/lelireleli/1/edit?html,output). Of course, you have to enter zero because it's the only number in the `[0, 0]` closed interval.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is max="0", so when the input raises 0, is invalid.
Remove max or replace it for the desired max value.

Input clean **without** max:

```
<input type="number" id="ee-amount" name="eeAmount" step="0.01" value="0" />
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/ev3966gw/

You can have more information [there](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_max.asp).